# Acessing object like by Index, but by name in C#

Tags: c#, properties, indexing

I have to classes, Father and Child (by example)

A snippet of my implementation

Class Father.cs

```
public class Father
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }

    public Father()
    {
    }
}
```

Class Child.cs

```
public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Child()
    {
    }

}
```

I'am trying to do something like this

```
        Father f = new Father();
        f.Children[0]; // ok
        f.Children[1]; // ok
        f.Children["John"]; // Duh!
```

I now, its wrong, i need to implement something in Child Class, i tryed this

```
    public Child this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
            return this;
        }
    }
```

But this doesnt work.

How can i implement this feature for my class Child?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or you can set it up like this:

```
public class Father
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Children Children { get; set; }

    public Father()
    {
    }
}
public class Children : List<Child>
{
    public Child this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
            return this.FirstOrDefault(tTemp => tTemp.Name == name);
        }
    }
}
public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Child()
    {
    }
}
```

Then you call it how you want.

Answer (score 6):

A `List<T>` doesn't have a string indexer; you could add one to the `Father` class, but the usage will be:

```
var child = parent["Fred"];
```

(no .Children)

For the indexer itself: Try (in the indexer):

```
return Children.FirstOrDefault(c=>c.Name==name);
```

To get an indexer on the list itself, you would have to create a custom list type and add the indexer there.

IMO, a method may be clearer (on Father):

```
public Child GetChildByName(string name) {...}
```

Comment: Thanks Marc. I know how to do this with Linq, but a want to implement the feature to accessin with indexers

Comment: Now i understand. i cant access objects Lists by string indexes

Comment: +1 .  Solving this problem explains why a lot of the .Net Framework controls use specialized classes for collections.  (e.g., `Control` uses a `Control.ControlCollection` instead of a `List<Control>` for the `Controls` member).  I agree with Marc that using an indexer directly is unclear.  The idea that `parent["Fred"]` returns parent's child named "Fred" is really unintuitive.

Answer (score 4):

In father class, you could write following code:

```
public Child this[string name]
{
    get
    {
        return Children.Where(c => c.Name == name);
    }
}
```

and use it like:

```
    Father f = new Father();
    f.Children[0]; // ok
    f.Children[1]; // ok
    f["John"]; // ok!
```

Comment: +1, the OP's **first** problem is that he put the `this` property in the wrong class.

Comment: Like this i will access the father with the name John and not the Child with te name John

Comment: That is not correct. Like this, you are asking father to look for a child with specified name. That's what father does in the implementation using Where() clause.

Comment: Another important reason you cannot write this in child class is that father has access to the `Children` collection. A child does not have this access to all other children.

Answer (score 1):

You are treating the List of Children like a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) (Dictionaries can be accessed by key).  Just change your List to a Dictionary and set the string to be the Child's name.

Comment: but in that case you cant access by index anymore :)

Answer (score 1):

You could make the `Children` List into an [OrderedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx) so that you can reference it by index or key and then add the objects with the name as the key. Just so you know though, any of these options can run into issues if you have multiple children with the same name.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the OrderedDictionary class.  Exactly what I was looking for.